# PowerMock : After Adding a particular class in @PrepareForTest, getting 'Invalid this class index 11012 in constant pool' error

Tags: java, powermock

```
@PrepareForTest({ A.class, B.class, SomeJavaClass.class, D.class})
class ReportActionTest
{
    // JUnit class having around 10,000 lines of code
}

class SomeJavaClass
{
    //Java class having around 10,500 lines of code
}
```

All JUnits of **ReportActionTest** were executing properly until I added few new methods in **SomeJavaClass**.
After Adding new methods, I tried to run JUnits of **ReportActionTest**.
But **ReportActionTest** couldn't load. 
Following is the error log :

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid this class index 11012 in constant pool in class file com/app/reports/web/action/SomeJavaClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:210)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.getTestConstructor(TestSuite.java:83)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit3RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit3RunnerDelegateImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:75)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:37)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:46)
    ... 20 more
```

Then I Removed some of the old methods(not newly added ones) of **SomeJavaClass.class**(Just to reduce it's size). 
Then I tried to run JUnits of **ReportActionTest** and **ReportActionTest** loaded properly.

So, I wanted to know, is there any limitation on size of the classes added in **@PrepareForTest** ?
I want to understand this behaviour, if anyone can explain.

Comment: put relevant code snippets

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The joys of working with PowerMock(ito). That framework has its place when you *have* to test legacy code that you can't refactor ... but honestly, the real answer is: when you need PowerMock(ito) for testing, then most likely because you wrote hard-to-test code. Not only hard to unit test, but also function test. We stopped using PowerMock some years back, because of strange errors here or there, especially when mocking static stuff. We now focus on writing "easy to test" code. And we do all our testing with *simple* Mockito constructs. And guess what: it just works!

Comment: And even better: that also helped improving the quality of our production code. So, as said: if you have a choice, consider to stop using PowerMock.